How do I approach row elimination for sets that consist of 2x2 matrices instead of 2 x 1 vectors?
I was wondering how to approach row reduction in problems where the given set consists of 2x2 matrices instead of 2x1 vectors. For example: given a set $C$, such that
$$C=\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\}$$
How do I concatenate them to form the augmented matrix if this was part of some linear combination? How to check if they linearly dependent using the elementary row operations and reduced row echelon form?
Additionally, the problem I am working on asks me to determine whether the $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ is within the span of $C$ using row reduction.

Welcome to MSE. Please use LATEX. You can use "Edit". Regarding your question, hint:$M_2(\mathbb R)\approx \mathbb R^4$.

$M_2(\mathbb R)\approx \mathbb R^4$
For example, by $\begin{bmatrix}a &  b\\c &d \end{bmatrix}\longmapsto (a,b,c,d)$
I find
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 1& 0 &-1  &4\end{bmatrix}\overset{C_3'=C_3+C_1,C'_4=C_4-4C_1}\longleftrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1 &0  &2  &-3  \\ 0 &1  &1  &2  \\ 0 &1  & 0 &3  \\1 & 0 &0  & 0\end{bmatrix}\overset{C_4''=C_4'-3C_2}\longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & -3 \\0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\overset{C_4'''=C_4''+c_3'}\longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 &-1  \\0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 1 &0  & 0 \\1 & 0 &0  & 0\end{bmatrix}$
So $\dim spanC=3$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1 &2  \\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}\notin spanC$.

Thank you so much for your help. I was just wondering if you could elaborate on how you proceeded to do the row operations. From my calculations for the augmented matrix, the reduced row echelon form should be an identity matrix.

Feel free to show your calculations in your post. It's easier to follow you that way.
